# client-maven-plugin - verifyAssetCatalog failed

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

Been trying out the client-maven-plugin from gluon but repeatedly getting;

> [Thu Aug 15 21:56:33 BST 2019][FINE] command to verifyAssetCatalog:
>   null --output-format human-readable-text --app-icon AppIcon
>   --output-partial-info-plist ../target/client/macos-x86_64/gvm/tmp/partial-plists/Assets.xcassets_1899711031185939387.plist
>   --platform macosx --minimum-deployment-target 10.14 --target-device mac --compress-pngs --compile
>   ../target/client/macos-x86_64/Agenda.app/Contents/Resources
>   ../target/client/macos-x86_64/gensrc/mac/assets/Assets.xcassets
>
> [Thu Aug 15 21:56:33 BST 2019][SEVERE] verifyAssetCatalog failed for
>   directory
>   ../target/client/macos-x86_64/gensrc/mac/assets/Assets.xcassets
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1090)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)    at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.DarwinTargetProcess.verifyAssetCatalog(DarwinTargetProcess.java:157)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.lambda$copyVerifyAssets$7(MacosTargetProcess.java:616)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>     at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.copyVerifyAssets(MacosTargetProcess.java:612)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.processInfoPlist(MacosTargetProcess.java:550)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.link(MacosTargetProcess.java:507)
>     at com.gluonhq.omega.Omega.nativeLink(Omega.java:86)    at
>   com.gluonhq.NativeLinkMojo.execute(NativeLinkMojo.java:54)    at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Severe Error
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.util.Logger.logSevere(Logger.java:62)   at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.lambda$copyVerifyAssets$7(MacosTargetProcess.java:619)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>     at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.copyVerifyAssets(MacosTargetProcess.java:612)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.processInfoPlist(MacosTargetProcess.java:550)
>     at
>   com.gluonhq.omega.target.MacosTargetProcess.link(MacosTargetProcess.java:507)
>     at com.gluonhq.omega.Omega.nativeLink(Omega.java:86)    at
>   com.gluonhq.NativeLinkMojo.execute(NativeLinkMojo.java:54)    at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <!--<target>ios-sim</target>-->
        <reflectionList>
            <list>${moduleName}.AgendaController</list>
            <list>javafx.collections.ObservableList</list>
            <list>javafx.collections.FXCollections</list>
            <list>javafx.fxml.FXML</list>
            <list>javafx.fxml.Initializable</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableColumn</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableRow</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableView</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TextArea</list>
            <list>javafx.application.Application</list>
            <list>javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.Parent</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.Scene</list>
            <list>javafx.stage.Stage</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.Label</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.SplitPane</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableColumn</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableView</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TextArea</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.text.Font</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment</list>
            <list>javafx.scene.control.TableColumnBase</list>
        </reflectionList>
        <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `gensrc`  folder and running `client:link` again? Can you post a more detailed stacktrace?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that - have posted the complete trace.

Comment: The error is in the first line, `command to verifyAssetCatalog: null -output-format `, should say something like `command to verifyAssetCatalog: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool -output-format `. Do you have Xcode installed?

Comment: Yeah I do - I've verified the path and the actual exists. Hmm, wonder why it's not picking it up!

Comment: Run this in a terminal: `xcrun -sdk macosx -f actool`, does it work? Then run `xcrun -sdk iphoneos -f actool`, does it work too?

Comment: Got it - I had the Command Line Tools installed before Xcode so I needed to run: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer the link now works. Thanks for the pointer @JoséPereda!

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` corrected this problem. It occurred because I had installed the command line tools prior to the installation of Xcode and needed to be switched.

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` will restore the command line tools.

Kudos to @JoséPereda!